# Roblox studio WaitForChild indexing as nil?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

Whenever i attempt to use the WaitForChild event, it doesnt work and i have zero clue why

```
local ui = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui").ScreenGui

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function()
    wait()
    ui.Enabled = true
    
end)

script.Parent.TouchEnded:Connect(function()
    wait()
    ui.Enabled = false
end)
```

The errors goes like so: Workspace.Part.ShopOpen:1: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

Answer (score 1):

The WaitForChild isn't returning nil, it is the LocalPlayer that is returning nil. I'm guessing since it's returning nil that you accidentally put it in a Server Script. If that is the case you can only access LocalPlayer through Local Scripts. By the way if you change it to a Local Script the `script.Parent.Touched` wont work as Local Scripts don't run in workspace, so you would have to put it somewhere like StarterCharacter scripts and instead of `script.Parent.Touched`, you use `game.Workspace.Part.Touched`.